PFS and PCS Game
Where can I find a formal security definition for Perfect Forward Secrecy (PFS) and Post-Compromise Security (PCS) that includes a cryptographic game model and a challenge-response structure, illustrating how an adversary would interact with a challenger to attempt breaking these security properties? Can you recommend research papers or cryptographic protocols that formalize these definitions, perhaps showing adversary models, game sequences, and proofs of security under such adversarial conditions?
